# C# list of mat to C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++

I made c++ DLL to import the c# project.
Now I am trying to make a function that gives the OpenCV sharp Mat list to C++.
I succeeded pass single Mat with blow code.

C++

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) void  SetImages(unsigned char * data, int height, int width)
{
    Mat mat = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, data);
    cv::imwrite("D:\\test.jpg", mat);
}
```

C#

```cs
List<Mat> matlist = new List<Mat>();
Mat m = Cv2.ImRead(@"D:target.jpg");
var pointer = m.Data;
SetImages(pointer, m.Rows, m.Cols);
```

But I don't have an idea for sending a list of Mats.
Thanks.

Comment: Need to pin the managed memory to get its native pointer. Search about `fixed`.

Comment: Could you please tell me in detail? I've got it :(

Comment: Copy to an array and fix the array and get the pointer and pass it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: Then how I could get them in c++?

Comment: If the C# `Mat` and C++ `Mat` memory layouts are same, `void*`, `char*` whatever even `Mat*`.